# The usage of the verb "change", change jobs, change schools, change phones, but why not "change doctors" or "change subjects"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, difference

I found myself curious of this tricky question, being that in the dictionary, it says

***to exchange one thing for another thing, especially of a similar type:
She's just changed jobs.
Let's change the subject (= talk about something different).***

in another dictionary, it goes

***verb
To change something means to replace it with something new or different.
If you want to change your doctor there are two ways of doing it. [VERB noun]***

To me, "change my doctor" involves 2 doctors, why not "change doctors",  isn't " change the subject" about changing from the old one to the new one, so how come it gets to be "change the subject". why not "change subjects". These 2 nouns should be plurals perhaps?

Comment: _Change doctors_ would be perfectly OK. _Change the subject_ is a standard phrase for when you want to  stop discussing a particular topic. Don't forget that _change_ can also mean _make different_.

Comment: yeah, tks. what about this sentence i saw in Collins Dictionary, "we change our car every 2 yrs". I suppose it should be change cars? but someone told me that change my job means altercate a project or change something about my job. so "change our car" means change some part(s) of our car? or replace our old car for a new one. Very confusing. :( If this is the case, change my phone should mean exactly the same as change phones?

Comment: "to change your car every 2 years" means that you trade your old car for a new car. You change one car for another, either way you own one car, not cars. That someone is wrong, if you change or replace part of something, that what it is. So, I have changed the lights, the engine, whatever, not the entire vehicle.

Comment: If someone says "We change our car every two years", most people would understand from the context that they mean 'exchange it for a new one' and not 'make changes to it'.